# Can't segue from button to UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting an error when trying to execute a segue from a button to a UINavigatinController:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
@IBAction func displayFootball(_ sender: Any) {
        self.configToSend = self.configFootball
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "navSegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "navSegue" {
        let navVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let mainVC = navVC.topViewController as! MainViewController //<--This is where the error occurs

        mainVC.config = self.configToSend
    }
}
```

[image]

The first segue is called 'navSegue' and the second is unnamed. Both go directly from one view controller to the next (not from the buttons themselves).

[image]

The navVC is NOT nil, btw.

Anyone know why this is happening? Thank you.

Comment: in your prepare statement, check segue name before taking any action to ensure it is the good segue. `if segue.identification == "navSegue" { //actions }` also `if let navVC = segue.destination as? UINavigationController { //actions }` most probably your navVC is nill

Comment: Are you sure Gameday Pocket Guide is subclassed as MainViewController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this, try to use:

```
let navVC = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
(navVC.viewControllers[0] as? YourVCClass).property = dataToSend
```

Edit:

The problem of nil on `viewControllers` array could be because you haven't a relationship segue from NavigationController to his first ViewController

The icon of the segue should be like this one:
[image]

Comment: That just gives me this error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'`

Comment: I think I have found your problem. From Navigation Controller you haven't the Relationship Segue

So remove your segue from Navigation Controller to your Destination and create a new one of type Relationship segue

Comment: that was it. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154925/discussion-between-giuseppe-sapienza-and-alex).